# How does Mutex lock work in this question?

Tags: multithreading, embedded, mutex

currently receive this question in interview and tried to solve it but unfortunately not very well with Mutex.

```
Mutex A;
Mutex B;
char kFirstString[13] = "First Value.";
char kSecondString[14] = "Second Value.";
void Thread1() {
 A.Lock();
 B.Lock();
 strcpy(kFirstString, argv[1]);
 printf("%s\n", kFirstString);
 B.Unlock();
 A.Unlock();
}
void Thread2() {
 B.Lock();
 A.Lock();
 printf("%s\n", kSecondString);
 A.Unlock();
 B.Unlock();
}
```

In thread1  `strcpy(kFirstString, argv[1]);` will print the content of argv[1]
, but  what the thread2 prints `printf("%s\n", kSecondString);` is not sure, it might be some garbage content, that is my guess. Please point out if my thought is wrong.

And I think this function might have dead-lock since Mute A is hold by thread1 while thread2 trying to get A, as well as the similar situation of B.

Comment: Why are there two mutexes? What is the A mutex supposed to be protecting? There's no shared data, at least not as far as I can tell. So why are there mutexes at all?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It seems to just be toy code that tests understanding of deadlocks. Of course mutexes are meaningless here, but in an actual code it may be locking two SQL tables for writing, for example, and the structure of the code might actually be the same, with the same potentially catastrophic results.

Comment: @David Schwartz  It might make no sense since this is just for interview and i agree with you there is no shared data and i guess they just want me to give my thought about any possible errors.

Comment: I would have mentioned to the interviewer that the chances of that code actually deadlocking are extremely small. Specifically, it's the window of opportunity for one thread to lock one of those mutexes in-between the calls that the other thread makes to lock them that is small. You could test the hell out of that code, and never get a deadlock, and then years later, you'd get a customer telling you how many millions of dollars they lost when their e-commerce site that went down, and it turns out that it went down because that deadlock finally happened.

Comment: I think what is notable is that **the threads should obtain the locks in the same order**.  When one thread obtains A first and the other thread obtains B first then there is a potential for a deadlock.  Both threads should obtain A first to prevent the possibility of this deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a given that this will deadlock. If the sequence of two locks is not interrupted by the other thread, there is no problem. However, you are on the right track.

One problem is that there is a *possibility* of deadlock, in a scenario such as this:

```
Thread1 acquires lock on A
Thread2 acquires lock on B
```

in any order; then

```
Thread1 tries to acquire lock on B, but fails since Thread2 has it, and waits
Thread2 tries to acquire lock on A, but fails since Thread1 has it, and waits
```

in any order. This is a deadlock. It is not certain (and in a non-toy scenario, not even *probable*) that the two threads will run with such timing to interrupt each other at this precise moment, but it is *possible* — which is even more dangerous, because it will pass testing many times and fail unpredictably at a random point in time. You want your code to have 0% chance of deadlock; "improbable" is not good enough.

Since this seems to be C, the other problem seems to be that there is no check to indicate whether `argv[1]` exists, and whether it would fit inside `kFirstString`; if the program is invoked with no arguments, or if the first argument is too long, trouble ensues. This is entirely unrelated with threads or mutexes, though.

Comment: Thank you Amadan! I guess this is not an intact program since it doesn't indicate the argument at first, i totally agree with you and i can understand that.